# Which force drives current in the conductor in this example?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a cartesian coordinate system in which there exists only magnetic field. At any point the field points towards X-axis and does not change with time, however the field is non uniform. If I move with constant velocity, a conducting circular ring along X-direction by keeping its axis always along X-direction, an emf will be induced in the ring. Whether this emf is caused by electric or magnetic forces? It can't be magnetic forces as as B is parallel to velocity. It cant be by electric forces as magnetic field does not vary with time. Then which force causes the emf?

Comment: So you are talking about the force caused by the change in magnetic flow inside the ring, looking at the derivation of this force should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

> It can't be magnetic forces as as B is parallel to velocity.

$\def\vB{\vec B}$
Not true. A non-uniform $\vB\,$ field can't have constant $x$-direction. It wouldn't be divergence-less. Assume that on $x$-axis you have $B_y=B_z=0$. If $B_x$ decreases with increasing $x$ then the field lines around $x$-axis are diverging, i.e. $\vB\,$ has a radial component and $\vec v\times\vB\,$ doesn't vanish.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer removed my doubt. I understand that you indicate the Maxwell's law div(B)=0, which implies that if By=Bz=0 then d/dx(Bx)=0 which means Bx is constant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only forces that have electromagnetic origins are summarized by the Lorentz force:
$$\vec{F}=e(\vec{E}+\vec{v}\wedge\vec{B})$$
In your situation the free charges in the (metallic) ring are moving in X direction so they get a magnetic force that make them circle around the ring. This forces varies with the position, as $\vec{B}$ is non homogeneous; it is a force acting on the ring's free charges.

Another force will act on the ring as a whole, and it is the result of the so called radiation friction (or Abraham-Lorentz force). Since the circling of the ring's charges changes frequency as the ring moves (because the magnetic field is non constant) those charges accelerate and decelerate over time. This causes them to emit electromagnetic radiation, which will require a certain amount of work to move the ring with constant velocity across the non uniform $\vec{B}$. You can find some details here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham%E2%80%93Lorentz_force

Answer (score 0):

Mobile charged particles in the ring are bound to the ring by internal constraint forces, which make sure the charged do not jump out of the ring easily.

When ring is moving in magnetic field, these constraint forces are changed to maintain the charges bound to the ring and then they may do work on the charged particles.